# How to loop through a list of dictionary and select specific key value python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have the following list of dictionary:

```
"Items": [{
        "Instance": 1,
        "SubInstance": 1,
        "Path": "To Sleep",
    },
    {
        "Instance": 1,
        "SubInstance": 2,
        "Path": "To Eat",
    },
    {
        "Instance": 3,
        "SubInstance": 1,
        "Path": "To Play"
    },
    {
        "Instance": 2,
        "SubInstance": 1,
        "Path": "To Work"
    }]
```

And I am trying to loop through the list and check for if Instance = 3 and SubInstance = 1 then select just the key value "To Play" and assign it to a variable path_result. User input variables to use are var_inst for Instance and var_subInst for Subinstance. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide code without syntax errors. Post the desired output for your example list. Include what you have tried.

Comment: Following up on timgeb's comment, it is definitely important *for you* to show the code that *you* have tried. The way I read it, you have a fairly good idea of how to go about, so why isn't the code you've written (you have written something, right?) working? What isn't working?

Comment: Seems like homework.

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in l:
    if item['Instance'] == 3 and item['SubInstance'] == 1:
        path_result = item['Path']
```

l is a list of dictionaries